# How to understand the Scala Language Reference?

Tags: scala

I'm reading [Scala Language Reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), and I have troubles with such syntax:

> UnicodeEscape ::= \{\\}u{u} hexDigit hexDigit hexDigit hexDigit
>
> hexDigit ::= ‘0’ | ... | ‘9’ | ‘A’ | ... | ‘F’ | ‘a’ | ... | ‘f’

(it is on first page in chapter one). How should I understand it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hexDigit is a character from the range '0'..'9', 'a'..'f' or 'A'..'F'

UnicodeEscape is something like `\uXXXX` where X is a hexDigit. If I read it right, you can have additional u's, but I wouldn't recommend to use this (and never saw anyone using it).

BTW, the rules for this are exactly like for Unicode in Java Strings.

Answer (score 4):

This is [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form), which is the standard way to present grammars of computer languages.

Answer (score 4):

This (some kind of) [EBNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

It means that a Unicode token is essentially '\u' followed by four hex digits which are defined in the usual way.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is being presented in BNF format.  Check out this Wikipedia article for an introduction [Backus–Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form)